# How do I Increment surrounding cells of a cell in a 2-Dimensional array?

Tags: java, logic, minesweeper

I'm currently creating a simple Minesweeper game and I want to write a method with parameters of row and column coordinates that sets the tiles to be mined, and uses for loops to increment the neighbouring mines of the surrounding tiles.  The method should return true if the square was successfully mined, and false if the maximum number of mines was exceeded, or the square has already been mined.

But I have no idea as to how I can begin writing this method, I already created the 2-Dimensional array, and attempted to make the neighbouring mines increment, but my logic is not all there lol.

The methods that you might be interested in is Display() and mineCount()

Here is my code:

Minefield Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Minefield {

boolean[][] minefield;
int[][] minedNeighbour;
Random r = new Random();//random number generator

int row;
int column;
int mines;
public int emptySpaces = column*row;
public void Minefield(int row, int column, int mines) {
    this.row = row;
    this.column = column;
    this.mines = mines;

    minedNeighbour = new int[row][column];
    for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < 5;j++)
        {
            minedNeighbour[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        do{
            x = r.nextInt(5);
            y = r.nextInt(5);
        }
        while(minedNeighbour[x][y] == 99);
        minedNeighbour[x][y] = 99;
    }
}   

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(". 0 1 2 3 4");

    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
        for(int j = 0;j < 5;j++)
        {
            if(minedNeighbour[i][j] > -1 && minedNeighbour[i][j] < 9)
                System.out.println(" "+minedNeighbour[i][j]);

            else System.out.println(" +");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public void mineCount(int x, int y)
{
    int i,j; //loop variables
    if(minedNeighbour[x][y]!= -1)return; //already used
    minedNeighbour[x][y] = 0;//used
    emptySpaces--;
    for (i = x-1 ;i<=x+1 ; i++)
    {
        for(j = y-1 ;j<=y+1 ; j++)
        {
            if(minedNeighbour[i][j] == 99)
            {
                minedNeighbour[x][y]++;
            }
        }
    }

    if(i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < 5 && j < 5)
    {
        if(minedNeighbour[i][j] == 99)
        {
            minedNeighbour[x][y]++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: please provide the entire program, also what method should return true/false? The purpose of this site is not to give you an implementation; it is to help with concrete programming questions. And how to write one implementation of mine sweeper is not such a question.

Comment: I agree with Jocke ... "this is not a code-writing service."  But also, what you're missing is quite trivial:  you should allow for variable bounds, and when you're looking "around" a particular point you must test to ignore any coordinates that are out-of-bounds.  Your logic here is generally over-complicated.

Comment: Apologies, english is not my first language and I try and word my questions as best I can, I was just wondering if anyone can guide me instead of writing code for me, I  wanted someone to have a look and tell me or even alter the code slightly and the method that I wanted to return true/false is the mineCount, this is also my second day that I have been programming as I have just started a course.